# Re-question: Shape of mouth is awkward

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

I'm doing rigging of the mouth using rigify.

Ringging seems to be good(I think), but when i open the mouth, the shape of mouth becomes a little awkward.

Do I have to make the weight paint work more delicate to solve this awkwardness?

Or Is modeling the problem itself?

Here is the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3n6i83715d95e3a/2b_11_mouth%20is%20awkward.blend?dl=0 Here is video that show the problem: https://youtu.be/dVGSkKjqIqw

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy going into edit mode on your mesh. Then, select the weird part and find out what bone you want to control it. Then in vertex groups click on the black arrow and remove from all the vertex groups. Then, click the group of the bone you want it on and click assign.